# How to run PMD for java 1.6 in Maven

Tags: java, maven, pmd, java-6

I am trying to configure PMD into a legacy application that needs to run in java 1.6 (this is mandatory). I am trying to find a version of pmd-plugin that was build at least again java 1.6. If I use maven-pmd-plugin it complains not being binary compatible with jre 1.6.

The problem is older version of PMD net.sourceforge.pmd  seems to be ignored and maven-pmd-plugin:3.8 always run instead no matter the version I use.
Now I am trying with no lucky with this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
    <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest PMD release to be compiled against Java 6 was PMD 5.4.6. (last of the 5.4.x branch). Ever since 5.5.0 PMD has required Java 7.

You can tell the Maven plugin to use whichever version of PMD you require by setting it's dependencies explicitly.

You can see the docs on how to do so [here](https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_userdocs_tools_maven.html)

Comment: >You can tell the Maven plugin to use whichever version of PMD you >require by setting it's dependencies explicitly.

Ok, but "maven-pmd-plugin" itself uses java 1.7 to run. I think I cannot use this plugin at all with java 1.6 running maven.

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro you can use the plugin version 3.6, which was the last to use Java 6.

Comment: Using version 3.6, 3.5 and 3.4 I still get 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/sourceforge/pmd/renderers/Renderer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
Do you know If I have to add any other configuration for Report besides 
...
 <reporting>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
    <configuration>
....

Comment: You probably have a config issue somewhere else. maven-pmd-plugin 3.6 / 3.5 / 3.4 used PMD versions 5.4.x / 5.3.x by default. You may have a duplicate plugin definition, check if you are inheriting from a parent pom or a child project overriding the config